# How can I fix "install joint_state_publisher" error (it is installed already)?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and learning URDF from **http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials** , I am at this **http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Movable%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF** tutorial and facing an error that says "you should install "joint_state_publisher" " which is installed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344142/how-can-i-fix-%22install-joint_state_publisher%22-error-(it-is-installed-already)?/) by [Muhammad Zaid](https://answers.ros.org/users/51762/muhammad-zaid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-14**:
Please don't paraphrase or summarise errors.

Add a verbatim copy of the entire error message (including a few lines before and after it) to your question.

You can use the `edit` button/link for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

thanks, but I was making the mistake. joint_state_publisher_gui was not installed (I installed it now), and I was confusing it with joint_state_publisher.
thanks again.

---

Originally posted by [Muhammad Zaid](https://answers.ros.org/users/51762/muhammad-zaid/) with karma: 16 on 2020-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0